# Heroku app continue to restart a Discord BOT

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hello i received the notification for ending the dyno hours for Free dyno.

I have activated only 1 app in the account (Discord BOT) that for now has only 1 command (that it's used less in a day).
I read on Heroku that after 30 minutes the bot goes sleep, but watching the app logs, it retrives errors not from the app and it restarts the BOT, 1 time each 1/2hour/s:

```
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137766+00:00 app[worker.1]: events.js:173
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137788+00:00 app[worker.1]: throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137790+00:00 app[worker.1]: ^
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137791+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137793+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ([object Object])
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137794+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Client.emit (events.js:171:17)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137797+00:00 app[worker.1]: at WebSocketConnection.onError (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:374:17)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137799+00:00 app[worker.1]: at WebSocket.onError (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:128:16)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137800+00:00 app[worker.1]: at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137801+00:00 app[worker.1]: at _receiver.cleanup (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:211:14)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137802+00:00 app[worker.1]: at Receiver.cleanup (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:557:13)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137804+00:00 app[worker.1]: at WebSocket.finalize (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:206:20)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137805+00:00 app[worker.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137806+00:00 app[worker.1]: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137807+00:00 app[worker.1]: at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.137808+00:00 app[worker.1]: at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
2018-11-23T20:10:48.209641+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I have retested the BOT Locally, and in 9 hours actived it hadn't retrived any errors, using it also.
Why? How can i solve? It's impossible ends all hours with a small bot with only 1 command, less uses by only 1 Discord Server.
(The only web requests are performed using the command, not coninuosly!)
Thank you

Comment: discord bots don't go idle like websites (which is the intended use-case for heroku). instead its active the entire time polling events from discord's gateway which causes it to drain the free hosting time instantly. If you want a proper host you'll have to pay for a VPS.

Comment: @Minn Thats not true. Discord bots do go idle. Atleast in most cases, unless there is some sort of a background task that keeps pinging the bot. I have 2 discord bots which have been online for few days but have utilised much less hosting time.

Answer (score 0):

Your provided `stack-trace` shows an error that was emitted by `discord.js`, but not handled.

For testing its enough if you just add `<discord.Client>.on('error', console.log)`

Also make sure your bot is using the worker Dyno

Comment: This isn't an answer